# Groovy is not evaluating in JMeter If controller

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

When using Groovy in JMeter `If` controller this expression is not evaluated. I observed that it doesn't execute steps inside `If`

```
${_groovy((Long.valueOf(props.get("myVar"))-(new Date().getTime()))>=5000}
```

However, when I use same expression in `JSR223 PreProcessor` just before `If` controller to check, expression gives result , which is greater than 5000

```
log.info("check expression: "+(Long.valueOf(props.get("myVar"))-(new Date().getTime()))))
```

I have tried this using `vars.get("myVar")` and `props.getProperty("myVar")` in `If` controller for same expression but I get same result. How can I write correct groovy in `If` controller or am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you check `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?,`?

Comment: Yes , it is checked

Answer (score 1):

I believe correct syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy((Long.valueOf(props.get("myVar")) - (new Date().getTime())) >= 5000,)}
```

If you're uncertain regarding proper syntax of JMeter function consider using [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)